# How should I replace a 6 wire, 12 gauge electrical outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am trying to replace a 15A electrical outlet. The existing one is attached to 12 gauge copper wire. There is a ground connection, one set of wire on the bottom screws, two sets of wire going into the holes in the back. Obviously, the existing one can accept 12 gauge wire in the holes in the back.

The new one cannot accept 12 gauge wire in the back (I read that code doesn't allow this anymore), so am I not sure what I should do.

Comment: Growing consensus is to avoid back-wiring even if the outlet is a back-wire set-screw type. Make a hook for the best psychical and electrical connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to use a pigtail. Use a large wire nut to join four 12 awg hot wires in the back of the electrical box. One of these four wires is the pig tail that will come out and join to the outlet at the screws. Do a similar arrangement for the four neutrals (one a pigtail) and bring out the single neutral to the outlet.

This arrangement also makes it far easier to mount the outlet after the wires are attached.

Don't forget the GND wire attached to the green terminal on the outlet.

Comment: Stab in or push in connections to devices were restricted by the nec.to 14 awg several years ago. If you find one that will take#12 it is either very old or it is a back wire device that requires the screw to be tightened to clamp the wire between the small plate inside that is designed to hold the wire. After connecting the wire always tug on the wire to ensure that it is tight this is a good idea for wire nuts too.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up a 20-amp duplex outlet with push-in terminals that will accept 12ga wire, that way it can be a drip-in replacement. 20 amp outlets have a t-shaped slot on the wider pin.

However, the pigtail method is just as valid. Really a question of which one is easier / cleaner / more convenient. Personally I would go the 20-amp duplex route if I had one handy (unlikely) or I was going to Home Depot for something else anyway. If I have a pocket full of the right size wire nuts I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Only if the breaker is 20 amperes. If this is protected by a 15 ampere breaker, you cannot install 20 ampere receptacles. The 12 AWG wire suggests that it might be, but it's not a guarantee.